# Ubuntu 18.04 cloud image does not release DHCP lease on shutdown

Tags: networking, ubuntu

It appears that Ubuntu 18.04 cloud image does not release DHCP lease on shutdown. I'm guessing this is because of netplan. Also, running "dhclient -v -r" does not send "DHCP Release" request.

Is there a way to force it to release the IP? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a known issue - https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10820. Fixed with new SendRelease option in systemd 243, which Ubuntu 18.04 of course does not have.